Purchase restore doesn't work in Unity 3D
I am using Unity 3D 2021.3.25f1 to build a game that I released on iOS and Android.
I have implemented IAP to offer ad-removal as a non-consumable purchase.
I have implemented everything as stated by tutorials/documentation and the purchasing itself works on both platforms. However I can't get the restoring to work. When I click my restore button (calling the RestorePurchases() method nothing happens and no further calls of ProcessPurchase are made - different to what the behaviour should be like from my understanding).
I have used the codeless IAP before but it didn't work with restoring purchases either so I came up with the solution I am posting here.
Heres my IAP manager. I have twp button set up calling the BuyProductNoAds and RestorePurchases functions. I am posting images of other settings as well.
Does anyone have an idea what's missing?
Thanks in advance for any help.
\
using GameAnalyticsSDK;
using System;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension;
using Unity.Services.Core.Environments;

public class IAPManager : MonoBehaviour, IDetailedStoreListener
{
\[SerializeField\]
private GameObject restoreButton;

    private static IStoreController storeController;          
    private static IExtensionProvider storeExtensionProvider;
    private static IAppleExtensions appleExtensions;
    
    private const string noAds = "com.mycompany.mygame.noads";
    private const string environment = "production";
    
    async void Start()
    {
    
#if UNITY_ANDROID
this.restoreButton.SetActive(false);
#endif

        try
        {
            var options = new InitializationOptions().SetEnvironmentName(environment);
    
            await UnityServices.InitializeAsync(options);
    
            if (storeController == null)
            {
                log("Intializing purchasing");
    
                InitializePurchasing();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // An error occurred during services initialization.
            logError($"Error while initializing Unity Gaming Services {exception}");
        }
    }
    
    private void logError(string str)
    {
        Debug.LogError(str);
        MainMenu.printToDebug($"Error: {str}");
    }
    private void log(string str)
    {
        Debug.Log(str);
        MainMenu.printToDebug(str);
    }
    
    //Methods
    public void InitializePurchasing()
    {
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            log("Purchasing already intiialized");
    
            return;
        }
    
        log("Purchasing not already intiialized");
    
        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
        builder.AddProduct(noAds, ProductType.NonConsumable);
    
        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }
    
    //Checks
    private bool IsInitialized()
    {
        return storeController != null && storeExtensionProvider != null;
    }
    
    //Actions
    public void BuyProductNoAds()
    {
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            log("Buying product...");
    
            Product product = storeController.products.WithID(noAds);
    
            if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
            {
                log("Initiaiting purchase...");
    
                storeController.InitiatePurchase(product);
            }
            else
            {
                logError("BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logError("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
        }
    }
    
    public void RestorePurchases()
    {
        if (!IsInitialized())
        {
            logError("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not initialized.");
            return;
        }
    
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer)
        {
            log("RestorePurchases started ...");
    
            appleExtensions.RestoreTransactions((result, msg) =>
            {
                log("RestorePurchases continuing: " + result + ". If no further messages, no purchases available to restore." + msg);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            log("RestorePurchases not started: not iOS");
        }
    }
    
    //Successes
    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        log("Intiialized purchasing!");
        storeController = controller;
        storeExtensionProvider = extensions;
        appleExtensions = storeExtensionProvider.GetExtension<IAppleExtensions>();
        appleExtensions.RegisterPurchaseDeferredListener(OnDeferred);
    }
    
    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.purchasedProduct.definition.id.Equals(noAds))
        {
            log("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: " + args.purchasedProduct.definition.id);
            // Add your code here to grant the item to the player
    
            //GA
            GameAnalytics.NewBusinessEvent(args.purchasedProduct.metadata.isoCurrencyCode, ((int)args.purchasedProduct.metadata.localizedPrice) * 100, "Ad Removal", "No Ads", "Main Menu");
    
            AdRythmManager.disableAds();
        }
        else
        {
            logError("ProcessPurchase: FAIL. Unrecognized product: " + args.purchasedProduct.definition.id);
        }
    
        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
    }
    
    
    //Fails
    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        logError("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error);
    }
    
    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error, string message)
    {
        logError("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error + ", Message: " + message);
    }
    
    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureReason failureReason)
    {
        logError($"OnPurchaseFailed: FAIL. Product: '{product.definition.storeSpecificId}', PurchaseFailureReason: {failureReason}");
    }
    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureDescription failureDescription)
    {
        logError($"OnPurchaseFailed: FAIL. Product: '{product.definition.storeSpecificId}', PurchaseFailureDescription: {failureDescription}");
    }
    
    //Other
    private void OnDeferred(Product product)
    {
        log("Purchase deferred: " + product.definition.id);
    }

}

\
IAP settings
IAP catalog
I tried codeless IAP, Tutorials and ChatGPT. I can't find a problem with my setup and especially the fact that purchasing works but restoring doesn't is weird to me.
